# Electrical device to keep circuit open once an open is detected

Tags: motor, labview

I'm working on a laboratory setup that has eight electric motors running at high speed. The motors are enabled by sending a 5 V enable signal from a NI DAQ setup/LabVIEW to the motor amplifiers. Presently, I'm trying to build in a manually-operated kill switch that will interrupt the 5 V enable circuit if anything goes wrong, thus shutting down the motors instantly.

One potential problem we've identified is that of an intermittent open circuit situation, where the 5 V signal is unintentionally interrupted by a loose wire, bad connection, etc. If the signal turns off then on, the motors will stop then start and immediately accelerate to the previously set RPM, which could be 7000 or more.

I'm wondering if there is a device that can detect an open circuit and, upon detection, keep that circuit open until the user performs some task such as resetting a button, or sending a signal from LabVIEW? Essentially, I want a way to ensure that once the enable circuit is broken for any reason, it stays that way until I can safely re-enable it. There are ways to do this in LabVIEW by monitoring the circuit voltage, but the program is slow, and I'd like something instantaneous.

Thanks

Comment: You need to implement an 8 input AND gate with a latch that is triggered by a low or a falling edge. If all inputs are high the AND output is high. If any input goes low the AND output goes low and triggers the latch. What response time do you need?

Comment: `kill switch that will interrupt the 5 V enable circuit` ... what would happen if the enable circuit failed? you really need to disconnect the main power source